# Octave code for gradient descent using vectorization not updating cost function correctly

Tags: machine-learning, octave, vectorization, gradient-descent

I have implemented following code for gradient descent using vectorization but it seems the cost function is not decrementing correctly.Instead the cost function is increasing with each iteration.

Assuming theta to be an n+1 vector, y to be a m vector and X to be design matrix m*(n+1)

```
function [theta, J_history] = gradientDescent(X, y, theta, alpha, num_iters)

m = length(y); % number of training examples
n = length(theta); % number of features
J_history = zeros(num_iters, 1);
error = ((theta' * X')' - y)*(alpha/m);
descent = zeros(size(theta),1);

for iter = 1:num_iters
for i = 1:n
   descent(i) = descent(i) + sum(error.* X(:,i));
   i = i + 1;
end 

theta = theta - descent;
J_history(iter) = computeCost(X, y, theta);
disp("the value of cost function is : "), disp(J_history(iter));
iter = iter + 1;
end
```

The compute cost function is :

```
function J = computeCost(X, y, theta)
m = length(y);
J = 0;
for i = 1:m,
   H = theta' * X(i,:)';
   E = H - y(i);
   SQE = E^2;
   J = (J + SQE);
   i = i+1;
end;
J = J / (2*m);
```

Comment: Shouldn't `for i = 1:n` increment `i` for you? You're also doing it inside the loop. (Long time since I did any Octave...)

Answer (score 3):

You can vectorise it even further:

```
function [theta, J_history] = gradientDescent(X, y, theta, alpha, num_iters)
    m = length(y); 
    J_history = zeros(num_iters, 1);

    for iter = 1:num_iters

       delta = (theta' * X'-y')*X;
       theta = theta - alpha/m*delta';
       J_history(iter) = computeCost(X, y, theta);

    end

end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can vectorize it better as follows

```
function [theta, J_history] = gradientDescent(X, y, theta, alpha, num_iters)
  m = length(y);
  J_history = zeros(num_iters, 1);

  for iter = 1:num_iters

     theta=theta-(alpha/m)*((X*theta-y)'*X)';
     J_history(iter) = computeCost(X, y, theta);

  end;
end;
```

The ComputeCost function can be written as

```
function J = computeCost(X, y, theta)
  m = length(y); 

  J = 1/(2*m)*sum((X*theta-y)^2);

end;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function J = computeCost(X, y, theta)
  m = length(y); 

  J = 1/(2*m)*sum((X*theta-y).^2);

end;
```

Comment: Please consider explaining your answer more thoroughly, instead of just providing the code to solve the problem.